# WPF MDI Application Using Prism (Composite WPF)

Tags: wpf, prism

So, I need to know how you implement MDI style applications using Prism, like having a shell window with a top menu, sidebar and status bar and be able to launch modules in child windows.

Any good example on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If refer to prism guidelines, you can easily develop things you desire as per following:

- Shell acts as Main Window / Page
- Add different views as regions in this shell.
- You need to use bootstrapper for initialization
- Ideally, you should not use child windows for
  the given structure of    UI. You should use plug-ins to show
  contents. For specific purposes,    you can use pop-ups.

Kindly refer to [Prism Practises] (http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) for details.

Please post if you have specific question further

Hope this helps.

Comment: saying "_you should not use child windows_" you break down the MDI concept IMHO. Child MDI-windows provide familiar behaviour to the user. Is there any way to keep child MDI-windows with PRISM?